# First Adapter image is incorrect

Tags: android

For some reason, my first image displays correctly, then gets overwrriten with another user's image. Any ideas:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        View vi=convertView; 
        ViewHolder holder;
        if( convertView == null ){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.userImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.feed_userimage);
                vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        if(user.has("image") && 
          user.getString("image") != null && 
          !user.getString("image").equals("null")) {
                holder.userImage.setTag(user.getString("image"));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(user.getString("image"), act, holder.userImage,USER_IMAGE_SIZE);
        } else {
                holder.userImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you customizing getView()?

Comment: at least show us the whole getView code! I will put the first answer but please show me the whole code

Comment: can we take a look at `DisplayImage` method.

Comment: I don't see any code that depends on the position here, not that it could be a problem, just pointing it out. same user Image for every list item? is that what you actually want?

Comment: all you need is revalidate the view after the image is changed.

Comment: What is user in this case and where are you iterating if its a collection post that code also

Comment: Isn't it easier to determine the content of the view based on `position`?

Comment: hey i got the exact same problem. Did you find any solution to this??

Comment: update to the newest version of https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fix

```
if(user.has("image") && 
    user.getString("image") != null && 
    !user.getString("image").equals("null")) {
  holder.userImage.setTag(user.getString("image"));
  imageLoader.DisplayImage(user.getString("image"), act, holder.userImage,USER_IMAGE_SIZE);
} else {
   holder.userImage.setTag(null);//add this line
   holder.userImage.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the correct image still shows up for a second, and then as the rest of the list loads, it is replaced with another user's image.

Comment: Does it work the same when you use my sample application? If not can you identify the difference between your code and my sample?

Comment: I mean does it work the same when you use my sample application from here https://github.com/thest1/LazyList?

Comment: Could you please give me a sample project with this problem? I need a way to reproduce the problem to debug it.

Comment: I have installed the latest lazylist from github and I'm liking the new memory management....well done! It might have also solved the issue. The jury is still out, but things are looking good!

Comment: But the jury has returned....bleh. I will have to isolate this problem sooner rather than later.

Comment: When I clear the cache before the list loads, everything works fine, however, if I don't then this problem occurs. I cannot give source, but I'd be happy to isolate some sample code. Any ideas?

Comment: I would be glad to take a look at the sample if you could isolate it.

Comment: I just spent 2 hours isolating the code into a sample project. The list rendered images correctly....until I added the ImageList into a TabHost. Tabhost is definitely introducing errors.  ALSO,I put your LazyList demo into a tab, and it works fine (after restarting 15x), but this does not change the fact that my code still renders the first image incorrectly about 10% of the time only when I add tabs.

Comment: Even wierder.....I read the same JSON from a file, and there is no problem. And I read it from the net, there is a delay and the first image is incorrect. And indeed, I remove the tabs, and load the json from the net and everything works fine. WTF??   FYI, I'm setting the adapter in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

It is happenning because you are using `convertView`. The `convertView` passed to the `getView` method is essentially a view object you had created (by inflating) in a previous `getView` call (which is no more be needed because it is not visible anymore, due to scrolling).

You are assuming that every time `getView` is called a new view is created, whereas you are actually using previously created views. The `convertView` is passed as an optimisation so that too many views does not have to be created when only a few are visible.
So the `setTag` call actually overwrites a previously created view's `tag`.

You should reconsider rewriting your code without using `tags`. Or, you could always inflate the view, instead of only inflating when the `convertView` is not `null`. But I wouldn't reccommend this approach as for a long list it would mean too many unnecessary views in the memory.

Comment: The reason you have given is correct, the culprit is Android caching the views and the fact that the getview(0) is called more frequently. But the fix is still not apparent. Still looking for it.